# How to fix const char* must match previous return type error?

Tags: c++

```
int plugin::feature(const InstanceInput &input) {

    auto parse_word=[](const string input_text){
        string text = input_text;
        int i=text.find("%");
        if(i!=-1){
            return text.substr(0, i);
        }
        return "";
    };

     ....
}
```

I am in Clion and it displays an error message at the 'return' statement saying that:

```
return type const char* must match previous return type std:basic_string<char> when lambda expression has unspecified specific return type
```

How to fix this?

Comment: as a side comment - you're making quite a few string copies here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
        if(i!=-1){
            return text.substr(0, i);
        }
        return "";
```

Try

```
        if(i!=-1){
            return text.substr(0, i);
        }
        return std::string();
```

`auto` return type for your lamda has been determined as `string` in the first case, and as `char*` in the second, which is a mismatch.

Comment: Important note: `""` is not a `std::string`. It is a [String Literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/c-string-literals?view=msvc-170).

Comment: Also, should I use i != -1 or i != string::npos for the find function? @user4581301

Comment: Use `npos`. It better describes the intent of the code. -1 could mean anything, but `npos`'s use is very narrowly defined, making the code easier to read. In general [avoid Magic Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad).